# how to fix the partial rendering if i have three or more drop down lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, renderpartial

If I have three drop down lists:

The second one filled when select from the first one

The third one filled when i select from the second one.

I put the second and third one in update panels to make partial post back but I note that when I select from the second one the third one doesn't fill at all!!

How to fix this problem?

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_camp" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_camp_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="300px"> 
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_fac" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_fac_SelectedIndexChanged"
                Width="300px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rVal_fac" runat="server" ControlToValidate="drp_fac"
                ErrorMessage="!" InitialValue="-1" ValidationGroup="G1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drp_camp" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_dep" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_dep_SelectedIndexChanged"
                Width="300px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rVal_dep" runat="server" ControlToValidate="drp_dep"
                ErrorMessage="!" InitialValue="-1" ValidationGroup="G1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drp_fac" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: How are you retrieving and binding the data to the third dropdownlist when firing the OnSelectedIndexChanged event of the second dropdownlist?

Comment: just on this event, i fill the third one and bind

Comment: Are you returning data from a database to bind to the dropdownlist?  Is there any data being returned to the object that you are binding to the dropdownlist datasource?

Comment: `private void FillDepartment(string fac_code)
        {
            drp_dep.Items.Clear();
            drp_dep.DataSource = FillDAL.DepartmentList(fac_code);
            drp_dep.DataTextField = "dep_name";
            drp_dep.DataValueField = "dep_code";
            drp_dep.DataBind();

        }`

Comment: yes there is data. when i remove all update panels, every thing goes okay but make full post back

Answer (score 1):

Try using cascaded dropdownlist. This works pretty fine which will solve your issue.
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can put all three DropDownLists in one UpdatePanel control, there is no need to try and handle the partial postback of each control.

You could use something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_camp" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_camp_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_fac" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_fac_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_dep" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drp_dep_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**NOTE:** You will need to add your RequiredFieldValidators back in.